# thread synchronization and priority in CPP

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to create a task manager, which accepts tasks and runs each task as a new thread,  using C++ and (currently) `std::thread` on a Linux environment .

- the task manager accepts normal tasks and priority tasks.
- when a priority task arrives, all normal tasks need to be halted until the priority task is done.

I'm keeping all normal task threads in a `std::vector`, but I couldn't find a proper function to halt those threads.
is there a way, preferably not using locks, to implement the wanted behavior?
maybe with `<pthread>` or boost threads?

Comment: There is no standard C++ way to "halt" or "pause" threads, other than notifying the threads themselves to pause their work.

Comment: From a design perspective, if each "task" is usually short-lived then I would rather recommend that you instead keep two queues of tasks: One for normal tasks and one for priority tasks. When it's time to execute a new task in your thread-pool, first of all check the priority task queue, and only if it's empty pick one from the other non-prioritized task queue. Or as an alternative, skip the pool completely when a priority task arrives, and create a separate thread for it to run immediately instead of adding it to a queue.

Comment: From an implementation perspective, you could get the `std::thread` native handle and use it to raise the priority of the thread (if possible) to make sure they get a higher priority than the other tasks, and let the OS scheduler handle the prioritization.

Comment: There might be some OS specific solutions like : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-suspendthread. But those will not be portable.

Comment: But yeah in general I agree, let tasks be short running and finish a low priority task first and then pickup the high priority one. You could set a time interval in which you want tasks to finish and report if tasks start to take longer then that so you can "guarantee" (as far as possible on a non realtime os) at least a minimum response time for your high priority tasks.

Comment: What happens if you pause a task just at the moment when it is holding a resource that will be needed by the higher priority task?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion

Comment: You said, "...runs each task as a _new_ thread." That's probably a bad idea unless tasks only happen infrequently. Creating and destroying tasks is expensive. Normally, when somebody wants a "task manager," they make/use a [thread _pool_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) that keeps its worker threads alive after they finish each task so that they can be re-used to perform other tasks.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thank you, i was not aware of this design pattern, so i read about it and it is surely a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to interrupt a thread from the outside.

Boost interruption points are handy to stop things once for all but that's not equivalent to a pause.

I would suggest you to implement your own "interruption" class with a condition variable (and yes a mutex) to check and wait efficiently anywhere inside your tasks. But it is up to you to explicitely call these interruptions.

Maybe another way would be make your priority tasks multithreadable so that you can allocate more threads to fulfill them => the scheduler is more likely to complete them first but that's not sure so forget what i said.

Sorry, I don't aknowledge anything better then this.